# Getting an error on Firestore's getCountFromServer()

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm trying to get the new `getCountFromServer()` feature released in Firebase 9.11 to work with Angularfire and/or without, but I get a strange error.
Case: I want to retrieve the size/length of the collection of members within an organization (/organizations/${orgId}/members), without requesting and reading all members docs.

Versions

```
"firebase": "^9.12.1",
"@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
```

Code (Simplified):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { getCountFromServer } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-member-size',
  templateUrl: './test-member-size.component.html',
})

export class TestMemberSizeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private Firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
async ngOnInit() {
    let collectionRef: any = this.Firestore.collection('/organizations/abc-org/members').ref
    let snapshot = await getCountFromServer(collectionRef);
    console.log('Test:')
    console.log(snapshot.data().count)
}
}
```

Error:

> core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wt')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wt')

Have any encountered this and can anybody help? :)
OBS: I do not encounter any errors on other Angularfire and Firestore calls.

Comment: Note that `getCountFromServer() retruns a Promise that will be resolved with the `count`. The `count` can be retrieved from `snapshot.data().count`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, you're right of course, I'll make an edit, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing `getCountFromServer()` from Modular SDK but rest of the code still uses `compat` version. It's best to not use both the versions together. Also, the new `COUNT()` function doesn't seem to be a part of `compat` SDK so there is no `.count()` method as in the NodeJS SDK.

As a workaround, you can use the Firebase JS SDK directly for the count function as shown below:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { getCountFromServer, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';

export class TestMemberSizeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private Firestore: AngularFirestore) {}
  async ngOnInit() {
    const collectionRef = collection(this.Firestore.firestore, 'users');
    const count = await getCountFromServer(collectionRef);
    console.log(count.data().count);
  }
}
```

However, I would recommend upgrading the code to the newer [Modular SDK](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/samples/modular).

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer. I just finished upgrading the whole code for the Firebase Modular SDK instead of importing compats and everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: Do you know if that's added to Angular Fire yet?