# Unable to import Firebase Firestore getCountFromServer in Angular "firebase": "^9.8.3",

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

Im trying to get the total count of documents in a subcollection within the Firestore using the "Count documents with aggregation queries" base of the Firebase documentation [Count documents with aggregation queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) in an Angular application.

I've tried importing from @angular/fire/firestore and firebse/firestore.

But prompt error: "has no exported member named 'getCountFromServer'. Did you mean 'getDocFromServer'?"

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an error on Firestore's getCountFromServer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124427/getting-an-error-on-firestores-getcountfromserver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'getCountFromServer' was introduced in the firebase version 9.11.

You have to install either 9.11 or install the latest to get all the features.